# Space time 3d map

Tags: r, 3d, plot

I would like to plot 3d spheres over a map in specific points. 
Radious of the spheres measures my variable in one time.

I have x,y for east and north axis in UTM projection. 
In z is the time and I have 2 observations in 4 positions of my map.

I want to present how changed my variable in the space and time.

The image I have in Shapefile or Geotiff format.

I saw another 3d plot similar to this one but not with maps.
[Example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16130025/attractive-3d-plot-in-r)
[Example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6720526/plotting-3d-data-in-r)

My plot should be like this one:

[image: Merida3d]