# What is this colormap?

Tags: python, r, matplotlib, ggplot2

I, literally, just need to know the name of this color map.

There is a figure I want to reproduce, but with updated data, and it would be extremely convenient for the readers to have it with the same colors.

Unfortunately, I do not know if this is native for Python/matplotlib or R/ggplot or any other libraries.

If you recognize it, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you so much!

[image]

Comment: Obviously, you already reviewed the [colormaps in matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/color/colormap_reference.html) by eye I assume.

Comment: I did! I should have made it clear in the original question.

Comment: As a wild guess I would say its the `'rainbow'` cmap in matplotlib.  Or are you looking for some kind of numerical way to find a match?

Comment: Either jet or rainbow. Here's an R example using jet: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20549540/how-to-create-3d-matlab-style-surface-plots-in-r/20553451#20553451

Comment: Looks like slightly desaturated version of turbo to me, but starts a little more purplish.

Comment: it looks like a cmyk translation of jet or turbo.  Note that when rgb gets converted to cmyk and then displayed again in rgb it will often look desaturated like this, depending on the colorprofile used.